# save value in session since TYPO3 10.4

Tags: typo3

i want to save values in a anonymous session in an extbase extension. Up to 10.4 it was possible to use

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'id', $data); 
$GLOBALS["TSFE"]->storeSessionData();
```

but since 10.4 this does not work anymore.

How is the prefered way in version 10/11?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [deprecation entry](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.4/Deprecation-85878-EidUtilityAndVariousTSFEMethods.html) gives me the feeling that

```php
$frontendUser->storeSessionData();
```

should work fine